# [InvalidOperationException: Displaying a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis

[I read that I have to use javascript for showing msg instead of msgbox but it didn't work the msgerror still is any one to help please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVDvf.png)

Comment: Please, can you paste the error message in this post?

Answer (score 0):

thank u for your interaction 
 if u click on the "I read that I have to use javascript for showing msg instead of msgbox but it didn't work the msgerror still is any one to help please"
this is the error message
Displaying a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.